# Check which things I can build with my available elements

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a list of available elements and another table where I have elements which I need to build things.

First Query: I would like to check which things I can build with my elements. (In example I want to get, all thing_id without 1 and 4).

Second query: I want to get all thing_id where I don't have only 1 element to build this things (in example thing_id=1)

You can test here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb1511

My tables:

[image]

Comment: Add the expected result(s) as well. As formatted text.

Comment: something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb1511/2 for firs query but results can be group by thing_id and i dont want this thing_id which have null in some elemnt (item is not available)